# Is there a way that I can simplify the adding of string, objects to the resource dictionary in Xamarin so I can do this with a list or array?

Tags: c#, xamarin

Is there a way that I can combine multiple setting statements into one when I am trying to set the Resource dictionary?

Here's an example of what I am doing now:

```
Application.Current.Resources[nameof(Fonts.CarouselHeadingFontSize)] = 24;
Application.Current.Resources[nameof(Fonts.CarouselSubHeadingFontSize)] = 36;
Application.Current.Resources[nameof(Fonts.ContentLabelTextFontSize)] = 13.5 * Fs;
```

What I did was to create a method to set these:

```
private void SetResource(string keyName, object v)
{
    Application.Current.Resources[keyName] = v;
}
```

Using it like this:

```
SetResource(nameof(Fonts.ButtonLinkLabelTextFontSize), 15 * Ms);
SetResource(nameof(Fonts.CarouselFooterFontSize), 16);
```

But is there a way that I can further simplify this setting to something like this:

```
SetResources((nameof(Fonts.ButtonLinkLabelTextFontSize), 15 * Ms),
             (nameof(Fonts.CarouselFooterFontSize), 16));
```

Note that the resource dictionary is

```
IDictionary<string, object>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Tuples in conjunction with `params`:

```cs
private void SetResources(params (string, object)[] resources)
{
    foreach(var (key, value) in resources)
    {
        Application.Current.Resources[key] = value;
    }
}
```

You can then call it like this (how you have it in your example):

```cs
SetResources((nameof(Fonts.ButtonLinkLabelTextFontSize), 15 * Ms),
             (nameof(Fonts.CarouselFooterFontSize), 16));
```